# Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined When Rendering Fields Based on Selected Multi-Picklist Values in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, multi-select

I am encountering the following error in Salesforce Lightning page wherein I try to render some fields based on values of multi-select picklist field:

[image]

I even tried **includes** but same error occurs. Would really appreciate any help or suggestions about this one.

Meanwhile, following are the current codes I have:

**contactLWC.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-theme_default">  
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                <div> 
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="MultiSelectPicklist__c"
                        onchange={handleMultiSelectPicklistChange}>
                    </lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
                <div if:true={renderField1}>    
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Field1__c">
                    </lightning-input-field>          
                </div> 
                <div if:true={renderField2}>    
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Field2__c">
                    </lightning-input-field>          
                </div>     
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**contactLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import MULTIPICKLIST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.MultiSelectPicklist__c';

const fields = [MULTIPICKLIST_FIELD];

export default class EditFSCalculationToolLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track renderField1;
    @track renderField2;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    contact;

    get renderField1() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data.includes('ValueA'), MULTIPICKLIST_FIELD) ? true : false; 
    }

    get renderField2() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data.includes('ValueB'), MULTIPICKLIST_FIELD) ? true : false; 
    }

    handleMultiSelectPicklistChange(event) {
        this.contact.MultiSelectPicklist__c = event.detail.value;
    }
    
    handleSuccess( event ) { 
        //some code....
 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access data from contact. Yoi are getting the error because of the way you are trying to access the data.

The `contact.data` is null by default as the value is not yet provisioned by wire service. In addition to that, the correct way to access data inside the getter would be.

```
return this.contact.data &&  getFieldValue(this.contact.data,MULTISELECT_PICKLIST).includes('ValueB');
```

Comment: I modified the condition statement and followed yours, it works now! Thanks for your help :))